# Windows 10 Setup won't load in VirtualBox (No VT-X)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Alright, I got a Windows 10 ISO finally (hooray!), but when I try to load it up in VirtualBox, I knew VT-X was disabled, but I continued as I you don't need it for x86 machines. But... All that happens is... This.[image: Windows logo only]

All I can say for sure is I'm confused. I've tried all three different drives (VHD, VDI, VMDK), and nothing is different. Different RAM amounts. Nothing. Please help.

Comment: VT-x is not necessary for 32-bit VMs, but binary translation will be used which is a lot slower

Comment: How long did you let it set at that screen?

Comment: about over 30 minutes

Comment: update: yesterday i let it sit for over an hour and it did nothing. got the iso from media creation tool so could that be the prob?